# Why is my Event Null?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using windows forms `C#`.

I have main `Form` and child `form`. The event is in the child `Form` and I subscribed to this event in the main `Form`. The problem is that when I click `button1` in child form it does nothing (it should fire the event so `textBox1` prints the text) because the event is still `null` although the main form has already subscribed to the event. Am I doing something wrong? Please help how can I fire the event once `button1` is clicked.

Child Form:

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myEvent != null)
        {
            MyEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Main Form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    ChildForm ChildFrm= new ChildForm ();

    ChildFrm.MyEvent += new EventHandler(HandleTheEvent);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm childfrm = new ChildForm ();
        childfrm.ShowDialog()
    }

    public void HandleTheEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "event is fired";
    }
```

Comment: how do you open `ChildForm`? also `if (myEvent != null)`: `myEvent` or `MyEvent ` should be here?

Comment: In which method of the MainForm are you subscribing to the event?

Comment: Yeah, if you have variable myEvent and it is null, you will never fire the event. But probably it is just typo.

Comment: Yeah, I'd suspect an old variable called `myEvent` with wrong casing floating around...

Comment: Your casing is still totally wrong, please fix this first (if that isn't even your problem)

Comment: @ Kzrystof . in "HandleTheEvent" method

Comment: @  Baldrick . I changed the name and still Null

Comment: @ Jerry Switalski. I changed the name and still Null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding the event handler to an another instance of ChildForm. Change MainForm's button1_click to look like this:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
          ChildFrm.ShowDialog()
  }
```

And your application should work OK.

Here's the working MainForm.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChildFrm.MyEvent += new EventHandler(HandleTheEvent);
    }

    ChildForm ChildFrm = new ChildForm();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildFrm.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void HandleTheEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "event is fired";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the event right after creating the form :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ChildForm childfrm = new ChildForm();
  childfrm.MyEvent += new EventHandler(HandleTheEvent);
  childfrm.ShowDialog()
}
```